# decrypting in RSA throws BadPaddingException when decrypting a string from file

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I used this program to output the encrypted string and copied and pasted the string in a file which I read and tried to decrypt. The program works fine if I try to decrypt strings generated in the program. It only fails if I copy the encrypted string to a file and then try to decrypt it. This is the error I got -

```
Nov 21, 2013 11:40:01 AM rsademo.RSADemo main
SEVERE: null
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Data must start with zero
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:325)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:272)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:356)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:356)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:382)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
    at rsademo.RSAUtil.decrypt(RSAUtil.java:112)
    at rsademo.RSADemo.main(RSADemo.java:65)
```

This is the code that I used -

```
package rsademo;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;

/**
 *
 * @author Test01
 */
public class RSADemo {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidKeySpecException {
        RSAUtil util = new RSAUtil();
        String path = "c:";
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyGen.initialize(1024);
            KeyPair generatedKeyPair = keyGen.genKeyPair();
            util.dumpKeyPair(generatedKeyPair);
            //util.SaveKeyPair(path, generatedKeyPair);

            KeyPair loadedKeyPair = util.LoadKeyPair(path, "RSA");
            System.out.println("Loaded Key Pair");
            util.dumpKeyPair(loadedKeyPair);

            PublicKey pub=generatedKeyPair.getPublic();
            PrivateKey priv=generatedKeyPair.getPrivate();
            byte[] data="in153".getBytes();
            System.out.println("Original: "+new String(data));
            byte[] encrypted=util.encrypt(data, pub);

            FileReader fr=new FileReader("D:\\Pankaj\\beta\\signageplus.conf");
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
            String s;
            String[] splits=null;
            while((s=br.readLine())!=null){
                if(s.startsWith("PASS")){
                    splits=s.split(";");
                    encrypted=splits[1].getBytes();
                    break;
                }
            }
            br.close();
            System.out.println("Encrypted: "+new String(encrypted));
            byte[] decrypted=util.decrypt(encrypted);
            System.out.println("Decrypted: "+new String(decrypted));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RSADemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RSADemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RSADemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RSADemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RSADemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (BadPaddingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RSADemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

The util class is as follows -

```
package rsademo;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;

/**
 *
 * @author Test01
 */
public class RSAUtil {

    public void dumpKeyPair(KeyPair keyPair) {
        PublicKey pub = keyPair.getPublic();
        System.out.println("Public Key: " + getHexString(pub.getEncoded()));

        PrivateKey priv = keyPair.getPrivate();
        System.out.println("Private Key: " + getHexString(priv.getEncoded()));
    }

    public String getHexString(byte[] b) {
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            result += Integer.toString((b[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void SaveKeyPair(String path, KeyPair keyPair) throws IOException {
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
        PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();

// Store Public Key.
        X509EncodedKeySpec x509EncodedKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(
                publicKey.getEncoded());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path + "/public.key");
        fos.write(x509EncodedKeySpec.getEncoded());
        fos.close();

// Store Private Key.
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8EncodedKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(
                privateKey.getEncoded());
        fos = new FileOutputStream(path + "/private.key");
        fos.write(pkcs8EncodedKeySpec.getEncoded());
        fos.close();
    }

    public KeyPair LoadKeyPair(String path, String algorithm)
            throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidKeySpecException {
// Read Public Key.
        File filePublicKey = new File(path + "/public.key");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path + "/public.key");
        byte[] encodedPublicKey = new byte[(int) filePublicKey.length()];
        fis.read(encodedPublicKey);
        fis.close();

// Read Private Key.
        File filePrivateKey = new File(path + "/private.key");
        fis = new FileInputStream(path + "/private.key");
        byte[] encodedPrivateKey = new byte[(int) filePrivateKey.length()];
        fis.read(encodedPrivateKey);
        fis.close();

// Generate KeyPair.
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
        X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(
                encodedPublicKey);
        PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);

        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(
                encodedPrivateKey);
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);

        return new KeyPair(publicKey, privateKey);
    }

    public byte[] encrypt(byte[] data, PublicKey key) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

        byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(data);
        return cipherData;

    }

    public byte[] decrypt(byte[] data) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, IOException, InvalidKeySpecException, InvalidKeyException {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        KeyPair pair=LoadKeyPair("c:", "RSA");
        PrivateKey key=pair.getPrivate();
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

        byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(data);
        return cipherData;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your encrypted data is a `byte[]` containing binary data (not text), but you're using it to construct a `String`, which expects the bytes to represent valid Unicode text in some encoding scheme — probably UTF-8 or UTF-16, depending on which OS you're using.  Since the encrypted data probably contains byte sequences that are not valid UTF-8/UTF-16, the `String` constructor will ignore the invalid bytes or replace them with placeholder characters — effectively corrupting the data.

If you want to display the encrypted data in a form that's safe to display and copy/paste as text, you should convert the `byte[]` into a hex string (like you're doing for the keys), or encode it using Base64, instead of passing it directly to the `String` constructor.

Comment: @pankaj It's not possible to write secure code by copy-pasting random examples off the internet. You need to understand every minor detail to produce anything that's even remotely secure.

Comment: Can you point me to a good place to begin? As it happens the more I read more confused I get.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with your encryption, decryption is you are not `encoding` the encrypted bytes to `Unicode` transformation by using some encoding techniques. We use `Base64` as common platform for generating such `encoded` byte sequences. 
A little modification in your encode and decode will do work for you,

```
public byte[] encrypt(String data, PublicKey key) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException 
{
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

    byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF8"));
    return  org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(cipherData);

}

public byte[] decrypt(String data) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, IOException, InvalidKeySpecException, InvalidKeyException 
{
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    KeyPair pair=LoadKeyPair("c:", "RSA");
    PrivateKey key=pair.getPrivate();
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

    byte[] byteCipherText =  org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(data) ;
    byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(byteCipherText);
    return cipherData; //// use new String(cipherData, "UTF8"); to get the original strings
}
```